# Hiding #N/A or empty cells from an excel chart produced by xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

Essentially I am generating a number of charts with xlsxwriter and trying to ensure gaps appear in the chart where I have #N/A's. Unfortunately it is not possible unless the show #N/A as empty cell setting is selected (I dont believe it is a supported feature as it is relatively new for excel).

[image]

I am currently using the following code to produce the above:

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook  = Workbook('chart.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

headings = ['Number', 'Value']

line_chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

line_chart.add_series({
    'categories': '={1,2,3,4,5,6}',
    'values':     '={2,#N/A,2,3,4,#N/A}'
})

worksheet.insert_chart('F2', line_chart)

workbook.close()
```

I understand that if I changed it to the following, the problem would be fixed, however my aim is to use the above approach. If its not possible thats fine.

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook  = Workbook('chart.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

headings = ['Number', 'Value']
data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [2,'', 2, 3, 4,'=NA()'],
]

worksheet.write_row('A1', headings, bold)
worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1])

line_chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

line_chart.add_series({
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7',
})

worksheet.insert_chart('F2', line_chart)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: should be related to your excel's settings. Since, I see gaps instead of NAs.

Comment: even when running the first code segment? I checked on a few versions of excel and it seems to persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately it is not possible unless the show #N/A as empty cell setting is selected (I dont believe it is a supported feature as it is relatively new for excel).

That is correct. It looks like that feature was added recently in Excel 16 (the XML element is `<c16r3:dataDisplayOptions16>`). So it isn't supported in XlsxWriter.

Note, it is possible to set the first 3 of those options using [chart.show_blanks_as()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-show-blanks-as):

```
chart.show_blanks_as('span')
```

The available options are:

- `gap`: Blank data is shown as a gap. The default.
- `zero`: Blank data is displayed as zero.
- `span`: Blank data is connected with a line.

**Update**: 2023-09-18 - Added support for enabling the Excel "Show #N/A as an empty cell" chart option via the [`chart.show_na_as_empty_cell()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-show-na-as-empty-cell) method in XlsxWriter v3.1.4.

Comment: Thanks - is it possible it could be added in if requested?

Comment: It would be technically possible but it would have very low priority on the existing [roadmap](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/653). Can you use one of the other options such as `gap` or `zero` (see my updates above)?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the above options only work for blank cells (#N/A or anything else is not considered as blank, unless the option I discussed above is selected which is not the default case).

Comment: Can you change the #N/As to blanks?

Comment: As in the above examples the only way to produce blanks is by first writing the data to cells. You cannot specify blanks in a series as I have done in the first example (because excel has no notation to specify blanks).

Comment: Added in XlsxWriter v3.1.4.